# Nextjs App Router: заглушка для Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, nextjs

Проблема в следующем: нужно сделать заглушку для Internet Explorer.
next не поддерживает этот браузер.
До использования app Router можно было добавить скрипт в _document и выбрать стратегию beforeInteractive, и если пользователь таки открыл сайт в  Internet Explorer, то редиректить на простую html

Однако, app Router не подразумевает наличие _document
его функции выполняет root layout (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration)

но root layout рендерится не так рано как это делал _document, и в ie уже мы успеваем упасть к этому моменту

Как это можно исправить?)